# Windows ErrorMessage returning the code and not the message

Tags: c++, com, msmq

I have some code that calls the ErroerMessage() function of a _com_object to return an error code in a try, catch.

```
catch(const _com_error& error)
{
   myError = _T("Failed, Reason:")+error.ErrorMessage();
}
```

Instead of getting the actually windows string out explaining the error i get the error code returned. In this case 0xC00E001E

I have included mqoa.dll to allow access to the windows dll for MSMQ

Ive used breakpoints and stepped through and found that the wCode being returned is always 0.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of `myError`? It looks like you're adding two pointers instead of concatenating strings.

Comment: CString& csError is the myError , i get the error message out saying Failed Reason: 0xC00E001E and the error code with it but i think there may be a problem getting the definition of the code

Answer (score 1):

`_T("Failed, Reason:")` is a const pointer to `TCHAR`. [ErrorMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7db325b0.aspx) also returns a const pointer to `TCHAR`. The `+` operator ends up performing pointer arithmetic instead of concatenating the strings.

If `myError` is a `CString`, you can use its [+=](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300548.aspx) operator:

```
myError = _T("Failed, Reason: ");
myError += error.ErrorMessage();
```

Or its [Format()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa314327.aspx) method:

```
myError.Format(_T("Failed, Reason: %s"), error.ErrorMessage());
```

Comment: Tried using both of these methods and i keep getting the same problem where i get the error code but not the string version.

Failed, Reason: 0xC00E001E is the output

Comment: @user, it *might* be that `FormatMessage()` does not know how to format MSMQ errors. Does it work as expected with a standard COM error (`E_FAIL` for instance)?

Comment: I that case, there may not be much you can do. If `FormatMessage()` does not know MSMQ error codes, using `ErrorMessage()` will not be possible. You may want to implement a message table yourself, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms700106.aspx) is the list of all MSMQ error codes with their descriptions.

Comment: i thought this might of been the problem initially and thought of doing this as a work around and was saving it as last case scenario due to alot of codes needing to be implemented. Cheers for the help and ill crack on doing it this way.